# AVD Not Booting E/dalvikvm No valid entries found in bootclasspath

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, boot, android-4.4-kitkat, eclipse-kepler

I'm unable to start my AVD. I've uninstalled and installed it 2nd time. Still the same. I have kept the AVD for approx half an hour, Still no luck.

Below is the Console log i get when try to run the Application in AVD.

```
[2014-02-12 20:43:02 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2014-02-12 20:43:02 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2014-02-12 20:43:02 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2014-02-12 20:43:02 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-02-12 20:43:02 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-02-12 20:43:05 - HelloAndroid] Launch canceled!
[2014-02-12 20:44:38 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2014-02-12 20:44:38 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2014-02-12 20:44:38 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2014-02-12 20:44:38 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-02-12 20:44:38 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-02-12 20:44:49 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD_for_Nexus_4_by_Google'
[2014-02-12 20:45:23 - Emulator] bind: Permission denied
[2014-02-12 20:45:23 - HelloAndroid] New emulator found: emulator-5558
[2014-02-12 20:45:23 - HelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

And attached is the logcat when starting the AVD from AVD Manager.

http://sdrv.ms/1bWRKru

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in mounting the data partition or its not available.
In a real device, if you have not flashed the data partition properly, with fastboot, the same issue will occur.